# gitweb 404 - No projects found when gitolite-admin push

Tags: gitolite, gitweb

Context:

- gitolite (v3.5-0-g4071623) installed;
- gitweb installed;
- gitolite and gitweb works fine until I add a new repository in `gitolite-admin` and push the changes

  - gitweb user: `www-data`
  - gitolite user: `git`

with:

```
usermod -a -G git www-data
usermode -a -G www-data git
```

When I add a new repository, gitolite changes permissions of `projects.list` to `-rw-------` (user: read write)

In order for gitweb to work using `projects.list` file the permissions should be at least
`-rw-r-----` (user: read write; group:read)

When I manually set permission to the file:

```
chmod g+r projects.list
```

, gitweb starts working again.

File `.gitolite.rc` contains `UMASK => 0027`.

Question:

**How to make gitolite set permisions `-wr-r-----` (u:rw g:r) to `projects.list` file when a push to `gitolite-admin` is performed ?**